# Where is the Application.Current.Properties located on Android?

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

Where is the storage location of Application.Current.Properties of Xamarin Forms on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xamarin Forms storage location of `Application.Current.Properties` on Android is:

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/files/.config/.isolated-storage/PropertyStore.forms
```

**Test**

In the Xamarin persist some property:

```
Application.Current.Properties["someKey"] = "someValue";
```

Afterwards:

```
adb root
adb shell
cd /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/files/.config/.isolated-storage/
ls
```

Demo:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/find/5.0.0) on github and  try to figure out where the storage location is .

Search the file `Application` , and inside the class search keyword `Properties`  .

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Properties
{
    get
    {
        if (_propertiesTask == null)
        {
            _propertiesTask = GetPropertiesAsync();
        }

        return _propertiesTask.Result;
    }
}
```

```
async Task<IDictionary<string, object>> GetPropertiesAsync()
{
    var deserializer = DependencyService.Get<IDeserializer>();
    if (deserializer == null)
    {
        Log.Warning("Startup", "No IDeserialzier was found registered");
        return new Dictionary<string, object>(4);
    }

    IDictionary<string, object> properties = await deserializer.DeserializePropertiesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (properties == null)
        properties = new Dictionary<string, object>(4);

    return properties;
}
```

Search the file `IDeserializer` and its implementation on Android platform.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!store.FileExists(PropertyStoreFile))
        return null;

    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = store.OpenFile(PropertyStoreFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
```

Search the file `IsolatedStorageFile` and its implementation on Android platform.

```
public class _IsolatedStorageFile : IIsolatedStorageFile
{
    readonly IsolatedStorageFile _isolatedStorageFile;

    public _IsolatedStorageFile(IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile)
    {
        _isolatedStorageFile = isolatedStorageFile;
    }

    public Task CreateDirectoryAsync(string path)
    {
        _isolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory(path);
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

---

At last , the implementation for `CreateDirectory` is hidden , so that we can't   get the exact file path , however I just show you how to get something from source code .